# AsyncIO python3.4 restserver

Tags: rest, oop, curl, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I am trying to implement a simple restful server using asyncio module in python 3.4 and not able to hit my endpoints I have defined. When I do a CURL (GET request) on the URL (http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/queue, I get an empty response from the server. I think there's some issue with my basic class set up of asyncio. Could someone point that out? Does the CURL need to be implemented in a asyncio way where it uses aiohttp to send requests ?

Here is my code:

```
  4 import asyncio
  5 import aiorest
  6 import json
  8 
 10 
 11 class Sample(aiorest.RESTServer):
 12 
 13     def _init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
 14         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 15         self.add_url('GET', '/v1/queue', self.get_handler)
 16         self.add_url('POST', '/v1/stack', self.post_handler)

 19     def get_handler(self, request):
 20         return {'Welcome': 'user'}
 21 
 22     def post_handler(self, request, payload):
 23         if not payload:
 24             return {'error': 'Payload not supplied'}
 25 
 26         try:
 27             json_payload = json.loads(payload)
 28         except ValueError:
 29             return {'error': 'Invalid JSON supplied'}
 30         print('Payload received {0}'.format(json_payload))
 32         return {'Payload Received Success'}
 33 
 34 
 35 def main():
 36     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 37     server = Sample(hostname='127.0.0.1', loop=loop)
 38     srv = loop.run_until_complete(loop.create_server(
 39         server.make_handler, '127.0.0.1', 8080))
 40     print('Server listening on port 8080')

 44     try:
 45         loop.run_forever()
 46     except KeyboardInterrupt:
 47         pass
 48     finally:
 49         srv.close()
 50         loop.run_until_complete(srv.wait_closed())
 51         loop.close()
 52 
 53 
 54 if __name__ == '__main__':
 55     main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why code is not working is a simple typo in the Sample class constructor `_init__` instead of `__init__`. After fixing this everything should work as expected.

**edit**

The handler method should expect only `request` argument, body can be obtained from passed `request`.

```
def post_handler(self, request):
    payload = request._request_body.decode('utf-8')
    if not payload:
        return {'error': 'Payload not supplied'}

    try:
        json_payload = json.loads(payload)
    except ValueError:
        return {'error': 'Invalid JSON supplied'}
    print('Payload received {0}'.format(json_payload))
    return {'result': 'Payload Received Success'}
```

**hint**

By the way, [the development of aiorest has stopped](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiorest/issues/36).

Comment: I am able to send GET requests but my POST always send an empty response back when I curl it. 
I initialized payload to request.data. I think the data passed using CURL is not getting set to payload in my post_handler. Could you point, how to set payload in my post_handler from the request object ?Thanks

Comment: Never mind, I used aiohttp to get everything working.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using payload = request.text() which returns a string and then json.loads(payload) since that's the valid request method available in aiohttp - http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#request